# GCC generated assembly and .code32

Tags: gcc, assembly

I noticed that if I run `gcc -S -m32 foo.c`, then gcc correctly generates 32-bit instructions. However, the generated assembly code does not have the .code32 flag in it. Is there any way of having gcc emit that?

Comment: what instruction set?

Comment: The idea is that you will invoke the assembler in 32 bit mode too, so the directive is not needed. I don't think you can force it, short of using inline assembly. You can of course add that line afterwards too, using your build system.

Comment: You may be able to simply add this to the top of your _C_ files `__asm__(".code32\n\t");` before any code in the file.

Comment: Be aware that `.code32` is only useful to assemble some code for a different mode than the current compiler target.  e.g. a 64bit binary might want to include a chunk of 32bit code that it can inject into something else, or write to a file, rather than execute normally.  It may be technically possible for your process to switch from long mode to compat mode (by changing its code segment selector), but that's probably not useful.

Comment: As Michael points out, sure you could put `asm(".code32");` at the global scope, but that won't stop gcc `-m64` from emitting instructions that will only assemble in 64bit mode.  (e.g. `pushq %rbx`).  So while this is an answerable question, you're probably going to need to tell us what you actually want to accomplish to get a *useful* answer.

Comment: I have a loader that runs in protected mode which loads a long mode kernel. The loader that GRUB jumps to needs to be 32-bit code and I'm trying to minimize the amount of assembly that I need, i.e. I want the page table setup be written in mostly C while the kernel (compiled with the same GCC compiler is 64-bit code). I got around it already by having the 64-bit kernel be a GRUB module, so they don't need to coexist in the same ELF binary.